# How can I stop, restart or start Gunicorn running within a virtualenv on a Debian system?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debian, gunicorn

How can I stop, restart or start Gunicorn running within a virtualenv on a Debian system?

I can't seem to find a solution apart from finding the PID for the gunicorn daemon and killing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed the proper way to do it. Start it with the `-p` option so you don't have to guess at the PID if you have more than one instance running. You can tell gunicorn to reload your application without restarting the gunicorn process itself by sending it a SIGHUP instead of killing it.

If that makes you uncomfortable, you can always write a management script to put in `/etc/init.d` and start it like any other service.

Comment: Thank you very much Cairnarvon.